# How do I select only one radio button from two different form sets?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, radio-button

```
<div class="div_services service_block">
   <div class="activenicksrv">
      <h5>Extreme Service</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="div_extservices">
      <ul>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 1</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 2</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 3</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 4</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 5</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 6</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 7</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 8</li>
      </ul>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('services'); ?>">
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B1" />
            <label><span class="price">$7.99</span> - 1 Month</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B2" /> <label>
            <span class="price">$14.99</span> - 3 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B3" />
            <label><span class="price">$24.99</span> - 6 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B4" />
            <label><span class="price">$44.99</span> - 1 Year</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtnbox-ext buynowbtnbox">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $csrf['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $csrf['hash']; ?>" />
            <a class="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Buy Now</a>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Extra Service -->
<div class="div_services service_block">
   <div class="extranicksrv">
      <h5>Executive Service</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="div_exeservices">
      <ul>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 1</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 2</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 3</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 4</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 5</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 6</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 7</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 8</li>
      </ul>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('services'); ?>">
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G1" />
            <label><span class="price">$12.99</span> - 1 Month</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G2" /> <label>
            <span class="price">$23</span> - 3 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G3" />
            <label><span class="price">$40.99</span> - 6 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G4" />
            <label><span class="price">$59.99</span> - 1 Year</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtnbox-exe buynowbtnbox">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $csrf['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $csrf['hash']; ?>" />
            <a class="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Buy Now</a>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have tried and I need to select only one radio buttons from either services. If one service from a package is selected the other package services shouldn't be selected.I have 6 other packages User should be able to select one at a time from these different sets of packages
please help.
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the name is the same, I bind event handler on input and name.

I don't know whether you use jQuery or not.

For convenience I did it below by jQuery.

Only thing I did is to add the event handler.

```js
$('input[name="service"]').click(function(event){
   $('input[name="service"]:checked').not(this).prop('checked', false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_services service_block">
   <div class="activenicksrv">
      <h5>Extreme Service</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="div_extservices">
      <ul>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 1</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 2</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 3</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 4</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 5</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 6</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 7</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 8</li>
      </ul>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('services'); ?>">
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B1" />
            <label><span class="price">$7.99</span> - 1 Month</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B2" /> <label>
            <span class="price">$14.99</span> - 3 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B3" />
            <label><span class="price">$24.99</span> - 6 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B4" />
            <label><span class="price">$44.99</span> - 1 Year</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtnbox-ext buynowbtnbox">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $csrf['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $csrf['hash']; ?>" />
            <a class="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Buy Now</a>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Extra Service -->
<div class="div_services service_block">
   <div class="extranicksrv">
      <h5>Executive Service</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="div_exeservices">
      <ul>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 1</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 2</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 3</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 4</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 5</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 6</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 7</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 8</li>
      </ul>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('services'); ?>">
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G1" />
            <label><span class="price">$12.99</span> - 1 Month</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G2" /> <label>
            <span class="price">$23</span> - 3 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G3" />
            <label><span class="price">$40.99</span> - 6 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G4" />
            <label><span class="price">$59.99</span> - 1 Year</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtnbox-exe buynowbtnbox">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $csrf['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $csrf['hash']; ?>" />
            <a class="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Buy Now</a>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not Working with my code :(
Its a codeigniter app and I use
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery-ui.js'); ?>"></script>

Comment: What will be the reason?

Comment: Is there any JQuery version problems?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping two form tags just keep the one form tag and keep the whole html in that form tag.

```
<form method="post" action="
<?php echo base_url('services'); ?>">
<div class="div_services service_block">
    <div class="activenicksrv">
        <h5>Extreme Service</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="div_extservices">
        <ul>
            <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 1</li>
            <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 2</li>
            <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 3</li>
            <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 4</li>
            <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 5</li>
            <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 6</li>
            <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 7</li>
            <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 8</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B1" />
            <label>
                <span class="price">$7.99</span> - 1 Month
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B2" />
            <label>
                <span class="price">$14.99</span> - 3 Months
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B3" />
            <label>
                <span class="price">$24.99</span> - 6 Months
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B4" />
            <label>
                <span class="price">$44.99</span> - 1 Year
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="buynowbtnbox-ext buynowbtnbox">
            <input type="hidden" name="
                <?php echo $csrf['name']; ?>" value="
                <?php echo $csrf['hash']; ?>" />
                <a class="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Extra Service -->
    <div class="div_services service_block">
        <div class="extranicksrv">
            <h5>Executive Service</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="div_exeservices">
            <ul>
                <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 1</li>
                <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 2</li>
                <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 3</li>
                <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 4</li>
                <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 5</li>
                <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 6</li>
                <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 7</li>
                <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 8</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
                <input name="service" type="radio" value="G1" />
                <label>
                    <span class="price">$12.99</span> - 1 Month
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
                <input name="service" type="radio" value="G2" />
                <label>
                    <span class="price">$23</span> - 3 Months
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
                <input name="service" type="radio" value="G3" />
                <label>
                    <span class="price">$40.99</span> - 6 Months
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
                <input name="service" type="radio" value="G4" />
                <label>
                    <span class="price">$59.99</span> - 1 Year
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="buynowbtnbox-exe buynowbtnbox">
                <input type="hidden" name="
                    <?php echo $csrf['name']; ?>" value="
                    <?php echo $csrf['hash']; ?>" />
                    <a class="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I dont want to make it all inside one form tag. How can I use one radio button selected from all forms.

Comment: you can use the jquery code: `$(document).on('click','input[name="service"]', function(){     
      $('input[name="service"]').attr('checked', false);
      $(this).attr('checked', true);          
});`

Comment: sorry, instead of using attr use prop in jquery code. like this: `$(document).on('click','input[name="service"]', function(){ $('input[name="service"]').prop('checked', false); $(this).prop('checked', true); });`

Answer (score 0):

you can disable or hide second form radio button if first form radio button has selected or vice versa

```
<div class="div_services service_block">
   <div class="activenicksrv">
      <h5>Extreme Service</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="div_extservices">
      <ul>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 1</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 2</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 3</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 4</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 5</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 6</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 7</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 8</li>
      </ul>
      <form method="post" class="activenicksrv_form" action="<?php //echo base_url('services'); ?>">
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B1" />
            <label><span class="price">$7.99</span> - 1 Month</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B2" /> <label>
            <span class="price">$14.99</span> - 3 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B3" />
            <label><span class="price">$24.99</span> - 6 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="B4" />
            <label><span class="price">$44.99</span> - 1 Year</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtnbox-ext buynowbtnbox">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $csrf['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $csrf['hash']; ?>" />
            <a class="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Buy Now</a>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Extra Service -->
<div class="div_services service_block">
   <div class="extranicksrv">
      <h5>Executive Service</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="div_exeservices">
      <ul>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 1</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 2</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 3</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 4</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 5</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 6</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 7</li>
         <li class="ui-corner-left">E Service 8</li>
      </ul>
      <form method="post" class="extranicksrv_form" action="<?php //echo base_url('services'); ?>">
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G1" />
            <label><span class="price">$12.99</span> - 1 Month</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G2" /> <label>
            <span class="price">$23</span> - 3 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G3" />
            <label><span class="price">$40.99</span> - 6 Months</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtn" style="text-align: left;">
            <input name="service" type="radio" value="G4" />
            <label><span class="price">$59.99</span> - 1 Year</label>
         </div>
         <div class="buynowbtnbox-exe buynowbtnbox">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $csrf['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $csrf['hash']; ?>" />
            <a class="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Buy Now</a>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

   /*-----It will disable second form radio button---------*/
   $(".activenicksrv_form input[name=service]")
    .on("click", changeEvent);

   function changeEvent(event){
      if ($('.activenicksrv_form input[name=service]:checked').length > 0) {
         $(".extranicksrv_form input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);         
      }
   }

//--------


   /*-----It will disable first form radio button---------*/
   $(".extranicksrv_form input[name=service]")
    .on("click", changeEvent2);

   function changeEvent2(event){
      if ($('.extranicksrv_form input[name=service]:checked').length > 0) {
         $(".activenicksrv_form input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);         
      }
   }

</script>
```